# How come there is no reference to the ImageView in this code?

Tags: android

Following tutorial on RecyclerView, I noticed that they use an ImageView with 2 TextViews to act as a line of data for the RecyclerView, but on their adapter they only refer to the 2 TextViews and there is no sign for the ImageView.
(Tutorial can be found here, and the relevant code starts at section 2: [Vogella Tutorial on RecyclerView](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html))

```
package com.vogella.android.recyclerview;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<String> values;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView txtHeader;
        public TextView txtFooter;
        public View layout;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            layout = v;
            txtHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
            txtFooter = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
        }
    }

    public void add(int position, String item) {
        values.add(position, item);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void remove(int position) {
        values.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(List<String> myDataset) {
        values = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(
                parent.getContext());
        View v =
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        final String name = values.get(position);
        holder.txtHeader.setText(name);
        holder.txtHeader.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                remove(position);
            }
        });

        holder.txtFooter.setText("Footer: " + name);
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return values.size();
    }

}
```

You see there is reference only to the 2 TextViews:

```
    txtHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
    txtFooter = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
```

But what about the ImageView? how does it work without even mentioning it somewhere?

Comment: The image on the `ImageView` is never changed, so there's no need to access it in the `Adapter`. It's just always `android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`, which is specified in the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have always the same image inside the image view. 
It is done through XML code:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:contentDescription="TODO"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

If you want a different image for every row as doing with text, then you can reference image view inside the adapter. But probably for tutorial purposes, text_view examples was enough to show the case.

Comment: Thank you, I was just sure that the adapter needs the data as xml even if it's unchanged (So that it can have something to "deal with")